# Detecting multiple touches at once (Swift)

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

Im using **Xcode 7, Swift, and SpriteKit** and I'm attempting to allow the user to use two fingers at once in my app.

Basically I have two halves to my screen, and I want separate touch-recognition for each side, and **simultaneously**.

Here is my current code below :

```
    override func touchesMoved(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?)
    {
        guard let touch = touches.first else {
            return;
        }
        let location = touch.locationInNode(self)
        let touchedNode = self.nodeAtPoint(location)
        if (touchedNode == touch1){
            //code1
        }
        else if (touchedNode == touch2){
            //code2
        }
    }
```

touch1 and touch2 are SkSpriteNodes that each take up a different half of the screen.
This code works well, as long as you only have 1 finger on the screen at a time.
However if there are two(1 for each half), which ever one was placed on the screen first is the one that is registered.

How do I make it so that both are being registered, and therefore code1 and code2 are being run?

Answer (score 1):

You need [multipleTouchEnabled](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIView/multipleTouchEnabled) property set to `true`. From the docs about this property :

> When set to YES, the receiver receives all touches associated with a
>   multi-touch sequence. When set to NO, the receiver receives only the
>   first touch event in a multi-touch sequence. The default value of this
>   property is NO.

**EDIT**:

Based on your comments, you might try this (making sprites responsive to touches):

```
class Button:SKSpriteNode {

    init(size:CGSize, color:SKColor) {

        super.init(texture: nil, color: color, size: size)

        userInteractionEnabled = true
    }

    override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {

        if let name = self.name {
            print("Button with \(name) pressed")
        }
    }

    override func touchesMoved(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
        if let name = self.name {
            print("Button with \(name) pressed")
        }
    }

    override func touchesEnded(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
        if let name = self.name {
            print("Button with \(name) released")
        }
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

}

class GameScene: SKScene, SKPhysicsContactDelegate {

    override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {

        let left = Button(size: CGSize(width: frame.size.width/2.0, height: frame.size.height), color: .blackColor())
        left.name = "left"
        left.position = CGPoint(x: left.size.width/2.0, y: frame.midY)

        let right = Button(size: CGSize(width: frame.size.width/2.0, height: frame.size.height), color: .whiteColor())
        right.name = "right"
        right.position = CGPoint(x:frame.maxX-right.size.width/2.0, y: frame.midY)

        addChild(left)
        addChild(right)

    }
}
```

Comment: Where and how do i set it to true? I tried adding the code `view.multipleTouchEnabled = true` in my `GameViewController` in the function `viewDidLoad()`. However this doesn't fix it.

Comment: @MarshallD It should work exactly like you are doing it right now ... Checkout the edit.